# Standard practice for .wsgi secret key for flask applications on github repositories

Tags: github, flask, wsgi, secret-key

I am building a flask web application and would like to put it on a github repo.

I notice that in the .wsgi file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/hashchain/")

from hashchain import app as application
application.secret_key = 'super secret key'
```

There is an application.secret_key for encryption...

I am guessing that the standard way of putting a flask web app on github would include cloning the entire flask app folder in it's entirety but NOT the .wsgi file?

That way, contributors can freely run flask in debug mode on their own localhost to develop it further and if they really want can deploy it to their own server (but will have to write their own .wsgi file and config for the server in their control).

Is this the correct way to think about it? I'm guessing if I put the .wsgi file on github it would be open season feasting for hackers?

- I'm also guessing that if I hypothetically already did this? I would need to change the secret key after deleting it on the github repo because people could just look at the commit history to see it!

Comment: Read the secret from a separate file which is stored only on the host system filesystem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general way to do this is read from enviroment variable:

```
import os

application.secret_key = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'for dev')
```

Note it also set a default value for development.

You can set the enviroment variable `SECRET_KEY` manually:

```
$ export SECRET_KEY=you_key_here  # use $ set ... in Windows
```

Or you can save it in a `.env` file at project root:

```
SECRET_KEY=you_key_here
```

Add it into `.gitignore`:

```
.env
```

Then you can use [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) or something similar to import the variable:

```
# pip install python-dotenv
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

application.secret_key = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'for dev')
```

Comment: I like the environment variable approach better than my file reading approach. +1

Comment: Thanks, you can read [The Twelve-Factor App#config](https://12factor.net/config) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the secret or any other sensitive information should never been part of a Git repository.

To illustrate that, see [`ubuntudesign/git-mirror-service`](https://github.com/ubuntudesign/git-mirror-service), a simple WSGI server to create a mirror of a remote git repository on another remote.
It does include the step:

> ### Optional secret
>
> By default the server is unsecured - anyone who can access it can use it to mirror to repositories that the server has access to.
>
> To prevent this, you can add a secret:

```
echo "79a36d50-09be-4bf4-b339-cf005241e475" > .secret
```

> Once this file is in place, the service will only allow requests if the secret is provided.
>
> NB: For this to be an effective security measure, the server should be only accessible over HTTPS.

The file is [ignored in `.gitignore`](https://github.com/ubuntudesign/git-mirror-service/blob/21a8be0c06c71036da67a0e8eee7914f7951e177/.gitignore#L2).
And [`wsgi.py`](https://github.com/ubuntudesign/git-mirror-service/blob/21a8be0c06c71036da67a0e8eee7914f7951e177/wsgi.py#L13) reads it if present:

```
secret_filename = os.path.join(script_dir, ".secret")
if os.path.isfile(secret_filename):
    with open(secret_filename) as secret_file:
        real_secret = secret_file.read().strip()
```